# In event sourcing, is it ok to introduce a dependency in my message class?

Tags: dependencies, event-sourcing

Following [Martin Fowler's explanation on event sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html), I have a message class that looks something like this:

```
ShippingEvent
{
    Process(Ship ship) {}
}
```

However, in my case, I need to talk to another component in the `Process` method. More specific, I need to access a repository to get some basic data. Is it ok to add this repository to the method, i.e.:

```
ShippingEvent
{
    Process(Ship ship, IBasicDataRepository repo) {}
}
```

I could put it in the constructor of my message too, of course. However, I can't pass in the basic data, because the repo will be called multiple times with different parameters, depending on what's in the ´ship´ object.

So is it ok to introduce external dependencies in the event/message class or is there a better way?

Comment: I think in the pattern as described by Fowler, Process is supposed to be a generic method that all event subclasses implement. If that is true then your 2nd approach would work but I think a better approach would be to pass IBasicDataRepository in the event constructor. That way you will have more options/portability available as you can now create subclasses that don't use IBasicDataRepository. OFT, I don't even think you would pass ship to the Process method either, that would also go in the constructor. That way you can reconstruct the entire system of events not just ship events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that whatever is listening to your event should have a dependency on a repository, as opposed to having that dependency inside of your message.

Your message might be used in different contexts and an additional repository might not be needed every single time.

I would suggest keeping events as simple as possible. My events normally transfer a data structure. A listener then picks up an event and does something with that data structure.

You can implement `IShippingEventProcessor` - this would have a dependency on the `IBasicDataRepository`.

Finally, events normally promote loose coupling. A single event might be published and then picked up by a range of domains. It might be the case that one of the domains should know nothing about the `IBasicDataRepository` dependency.

Comment: Let me just add, that the event class should have a single responsibility, and that would be to provide information about the event in question. It sounds an awful lot like needing a repository means the class is doing something else as well.

Comment: I introduced a new class to process the event/handle the message. Just like you said.

Comment: Also, in large systems, it's quite possible that your events will need to be consumed by another piece of software on another computer running a completely different language. Another good reason why events should be pure immutable data-holders.